# Where is the main app class in an Android kotlin project?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android app dev, and I'm trying to use a library (LocaleHelper) that says to extend my App class:

```
class App : LocaleAwareApp() {
}
```

And to extend my base activity class:

```
open class BaseActivity : LocaleAwareCompatActivity() {  
}
```

but I don't have either of these in my Android Kotlin project. All I see for source code generated is the MainActivity class.

I'm using Android Studio 3.4.2 with min sdk set to 22. Is there a different way to integrate this library?

Comment: for what it's worth, it's the same for java :D just a note for future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new App class like this:

```
class App : LocaleAwareApp() {
}
```

and in AndroidManifest add this line inside the application tag:

```
android:name=".App"
```

After that you create a BaseActivityClass:

```
open class BaseActivity : LocaleAwareCompatActivity() {  
}
```

and your MainActivity and every other activity you create should inherit from this BaseActivity like this:

```
class MainActivity: BaseActivity() {
}
```

For more customization you should look into https://github.com/zeugma-solutions/locale-helper-android

Comment: Wow, talk about confusing! I wish that people would document their code/instructions more clearly. On the other hand, I'm new to Android, so I could be considered quite the noob. ;)

Comment: If you need more help feel free to ask. If this answer helped please accept it ;)

Comment: So now after doing that, I'm seeing the error: " Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath: 
" One of the class paths is the library's LocaleAwareCompatActivity, and the other is AppCompatActivity. I put the download link in the gradle file at the module level: implementation 'com.zeugmasolutions.localehelper:locale-helper-android:1.0.2'

What else do I need to do?

Comment: I also did a gradle file sync to see if that would help, but it did not. I know the files were downloaded because I can navigate to them with cmd+click

Comment: Never mind! I searched and found the solution. I had to select the magic command "Invalidate Cache/Restart...". Damn, Android dev is clunky as hell!

Comment: Nice to hear :)

Comment: Oops, spoke too soon. Still the same problem. It was indexing in the background and thought it was fixed. ;( I must be leaving out some type of configuration when setting up a library like this.

Answer (score 1):

App (I assume you mean Application) and Activity classes are part of the std android library, so you don't have to "have them". Extending them means you have to write your own implementation with "extends Activity" and "extends Application" in class prototype.
more info here: https://medium.com/@balakrishnanpt/android-application-class-a8a1d64c82d1

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean [this library](https://github.com/zeugma-solutions/locale-helper-android), `LocaleAwareApplication` is a class in the library. You would [create a subclass of it in your project](https://github.com/zeugma-solutions/locale-helper-android/blob/v1.0.1/app/src/main/java/com/zeugmasolutions/localeexample/Application.kt):

```
class MyAwesomeApplication : LocaleAwareApplication() {
}
```

Then, in your manifest, in the `<application>` tag, add an `android:name` attribute that points to your subclass:

```
<application android:name=".MyAwesomeApplication"
  // other attributes go here
>
```

I do not know why the `README` has the wrong class name (`LocaleAwareApp` instead of `LocaleAwareApplication`).